# Galleria code not working after JS popup added to menu

Tags: javascript, html, popup, galleria

i need some help.

I can't figure out why this code isn't working anymore. more specifically, its ignoring the thumbnails:false; trigger.

Everything else works except for that, and dreamweaver highlights  as unclosed when it is.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
<body>
<div class="w-container">
<div class="w-row header">
  <div class="w-col w-col-3">
    <img src="images/header-logo.png" width="200" alt="5359c20f0548c9ed470000c8_header-logo.png">
  </div><!--close w-col w-col-3-->
  <div class="w-col w-col-9 nav-column"><a class="w-inline-block nav-link" href="index.html"><h3>Main</h3></a><a class="w-inline-block nav-link" href="portfolio.php"><h3>Portfolio</h3></a><a class="w-inline-block nav-link" href="http://outtamymindphoto.ca/blog" target="_blank"><h3>Blog</h3></a>
    <a
    class="w-inline-block nav-link" href="index.html">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      </a>
  </div><!--close w-col w-col-9 nav-column-->
</div><!--close w-row header-->
</div><!--close w-container-->
    <div class="portfolio-main-image">
    <div id="galleria">
            <?php

            $images = glob('images/creative/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
            foreach ($images as $image) {
              {

              ?>  

            <img src ="<?php echo $image;  ?> " rel="galleria[galleria] "
            img data-big="<?php echo $image; ?>"  />


            <?php
              }
            } ?>
                <script>
      // Load the classic theme
            Galleria.loadTheme('./js/galleria.classic.min.js');
            // Hide caption button
            Galleria.configure({
                showInfo: false, 
                history:true,
                lightbox:true,
                fullscreenDoubleTap:true,
                swipe:true,
                thumbnails: false,
            });
            // Initialize Galleria
            Galleria.run('#galleria');
    </script>
        </div><!--close Galleria-->
    </div><!--close Portfolio-main-image-->
<div class="portfolio-selector">
<div class="portfolio-center">
    <div class="w-container portfolio-select">
        <?php 

    require('./includes/portmenu.php');

    ?>
    </div><!--close w-container portfolio-select-->
</div><!--close portfolio-center-->
</div><!--close portfolio-selector-->
<div class="w-container footer">
<div class="w-row">
  <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-clearfix">
    <div class="made-by">Made by Webflow.com</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-6 w-clearfix">
    <div class="hosted">Hosted by MITVIS.com</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/webflow.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><script   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js">    </script><![endif]-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

its a quick and dirty way, but i added the following to the Galleria CSS which has hidden the thumbnails again.

```
<style>
.galleria-thumbnails{
display:none;
}
</style>
```